# May I know how this integral was evaluated using hypergeometric function?

Tags: integration, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I can not solve the following integral using the hypergeometric function:

$$\int_a^b (\sin x)^{(1/n)}dx$$

Wolframalpha showed the [following result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&equal=Submit&i=integrate+(sinx)%5E(1%2Fn)).

[image: picture]

but I do not understand how Wolframalpha came to this result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of WolframAlpha can be obtained by the change of variables $t=\cos^2 x, dt=-2\cos x\sin x\,dx$ and subsequent expansion of the initial integral:
\begin{align}
\int \sin^a x\,dx=&-\frac12\int\frac{\sin^{a-1}x}{\cos x}\left(-2\cos x\sin x\right)dx=\\=&-\frac12\int t^{-\frac12}\left(1-t\right)^{\frac{a-1}{2}}dt=\\
=&-\frac12\int t^{-\frac12}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{1-a}{2}\right)_kt^k}{k!}\right)dt=\\
=&-\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{1-a}{2}\right)_k t^{k+\frac12}}{k!\left(k+\frac12\right)}=-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{1-a}{2}\right)_k \left(\frac12\right)_kt^{k+\frac12}}{\left(\frac32\right)_kk!}=\\
=&-t^{\frac12}{}_2F_1\left(\frac12,\frac{1-a}{2};\frac32;t\right).
\end{align}
Here $(\alpha)_k=\frac{\Gamma(a+k)}{\Gamma(a)}$ denotes the Pochhammer's symbol.

Comment: Thank you very very much !